# Finish work on EJB3 even after timeout

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, weblogic, ejb-3.0

I am designing webservices for an order system. When I have receive a order, it hast to add around 10000 entities in a table. It can be more. But as I am understanding this work will not finished in transaction time and will get timeout and all the works will be role back. But I want the service to finish it's work even after transaction time has past. How can I achive that? We are using EJB3 in WebLogic 11g with jdk 1.6.25.

Comment: We use a kind of batch processing for large data sets, but then you only can assure the consistency of data in one set, not over all sets, because you don't have a single big transaction.

Comment: Our system is designing in such a way that consistency is checked else where before. So consistency is not a problem.

Comment: Do you need to know the final outcome of this processing before returning from the method?

Comment: Not at all. As I am saving and checking the status from database with an another service.

Answer (score 1):

You can set transaction timeout: Services -> JTA, set the Timeout Seconds param value. By default this value is 30 seconds.

If your transactions is very long may be you have change your app architecture. You can insert rows without transactions (but you can lost your data consistency) or use butch update with one portion of data per transaction.

For insert rows without transaction you can use @TranscactionAttribute with [TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try JMS with MDB for long running processes.

Answer (score 0):

If consistency is not a problem and it's checked elsewhere then you should update the database records outside of ttransaction scope. So save what needs to go to db in a place where its quick. And let the actual db insertion happen in a non transacted session later on.